# Where to check weblogic server xmlbeans version that it loads and how to point to custom lib version?

Tags: oracle-adf

I am trying to upgrade my Oracle ADF application's apache poi from 3.17 to latest 5
Facing difficulties in xmlbeans version mismatch and class loader

Answer (score 0):

Tell us your exact JDeveloper version, please!
This isn't an ADF or Jdeveloper problem but a server class loader problem.
It can be easily fixed by telling the server to prefer the libraries you install with your application. The class loader then uses your jar version before looking into already loaded ones.
See https://tompeez.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/pitfalls-when-using-newer-versioned-libraries-than-shipped-with-jdeveloper-or-weblogic-server/